# How to use word "emanate"

Tags: word-usage

Are these two sentences correct?

But it did not take long before the problem started to emanate?

But it did not take long before the problem started to emanate itself?

Comment: I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @Kitfox: Interesting ambiguity there. ***I*** think you ***know*** what it means (it's not that you don't *think* it means whatever OP thinks it does; you *know* it doesn't mean what you assume OP thinks it does! :)

Comment: Kit is being polite :).

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use *escalate*?

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of emanate as listed by [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emanate?q=EMANATE) is:

> EMANATE     verb
>       1.  [no object] (emanate from)
>           (of a feeling, quality, or sensation) issue or spread out from (a source):
>               warmth emanated from the fireplace
>               she felt an undeniable charm emanating from him.
>       2. originate from; be produced by:
>               the proposals emanated from a committee
>       3. [with object] give out or emit (a feeling, quality, or sensation):
>               he emanated a powerful brooding air.

I do not think emanate, the way you have used it, fits any of these meanings. Neither sentence seems correct. Is **manifest** the word you are looking for, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Both usages are incorrect. The word you are looking for is *manifest* or a synonym thereof. *Emanate* means to diffuse or radiate something from some source.